# How to display a value in another table by using a function in django

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to make search_fields able to search for fields in another table on the django admin page. I discovered that I could use a function to achieve my goal, but when I went to the admin page, in place of the data I wanted it to display, it would display <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000208375C9280>

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import RiskRegister, Category, Severity, RSev
from account.models import Account

class RiskRegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'user_dept', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity',
                    'action_taken_explanation', 'created_at']
    list_filter = ['id', 'user', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity', 'action_taken_explanation']
    search_fields = ['id', 'user', 'user_dept', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity', 'created_at']
    def user_dept(self, obj):
        return Account.department
```

And my models.py file containing the Account model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username        = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=254, unique=True)
    department      = models.CharField(verbose_name='department', max_length=100, editable=True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='first name', max_length=254, blank=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(verbose_name='last name', max_length=254, blank=True)
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login      = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I make it display what is in the department?

Comment: What model is `RiskRegisterAdmin` managing? `Account`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `obj` is the model object here, you can this present this with `obj.user.department`:

```
class RiskRegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'user_dept', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity',
                    'action_taken_explanation', 'created_at']
    list_filter = ['id', 'user', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity', 'action_taken_explanation']
    search_fields = ['id', 'user', 'user_dept', 'date', 'category', 'roles', 'responderID', 'severity', 'created_at']
    
    def user_dept(self, obj):
        return obj.user.department
```

You can boost efficiency with a [**`.select_related(…)`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
class RiskRegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ⋮
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_related('user')
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, the change in the return prompt cleared the error. Really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: The user_dept field appears in list display, but when I attempt to put it in list_filter, it returns an error on the command prompt, saying that it does not refer to a field. Do I have to create a field for it?

Comment: @IyanuoluwaLoko: you should use `user__department` in the `list_filter`.

Comment: Okay. How about search_fields?

Comment: How do I reference the user department in search_fields

Comment: @IyanuoluwaLoko: the same way: `user__department`.

Comment: thanks again. Project works as expected